# Select Column value based on two values in another column

Tags: mysql

I am using the below table:

```
1   0051ML66220600132482    06:00:00        06:00:00        1538    100 0   1
2   0051ML66220600132482    06:00:00        06:00:00        1540    200 0   0
3   0051ML66220600132482    06:00:00        06:00:00        1541    300 0   0
4   0051ML66220600132482    06:01:00        06:01:00        1542    400 0   0
5   0051ML66220600132482    06:01:00        06:01:00        1543    500 0   0
6   0051ML66220600132482    06:02:00        06:02:00        1544    600 0   0
7   0051ML66220600132482    06:03:00        06:03:00        1546    700 0   0
```

Table structure is like below:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
--  TABLE stop_times
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
CREATE TABLE stop_times 
( 
    id int(12),   
    trip_id varchar(100),
    arrival_time varchar(8),
    arrival_time_seconds int(100),
    departure_time varchar(8),
    departure_time_seconds int(100),
    stop_id varchar(100),
    stop_sequence varchar(100),
    pickup_type varchar(2),
    drop_off_type varchar(2)
);
```

I am attempting to get `DISTINCT trip_id` if it matches both the destination and arrival `stop_id`

I have tried the below SQL with no luck:

```
select DISTINCT trip_id from stop_times where stop_id=1538 AND stop_id =1540;
```

Where it should produce: `0051ML66220600132482`

I have also tried an `INNER JOIN` like below:

```
SELECT 
    t.trip_id,
    start_s.stop_name as departure_stop,
    end_s.stop_name as arrival_stop
FROM trips t 
INNER JOIN stop_times start_st ON t.trip_id = start_st.trip_id
INNER JOIN stops start_s ON start_st.stop_id = start_s.stop_id
INNER JOIN stop_times end_st ON t.trip_id = end_st.trip_id
INNER JOIN stops end_s ON end_st.stop_id = end_s.stop_id
WHERE 
   start_s.stop_id = 1538 
  AND end_s.stop_id = 1540;
```

But it is sooo slow, and takes about 8-15 seconds for this simple query.

Explain Added:

[image]

What is the fastest/best way to write this query?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE stop_times ADD INDEX stop_trip_IX (stop_id, trip_id) ;` The stop_trip_IX is just a name for the index (so you know when it appears in EXPLAIN that it is used and in case you want to delete it later), you can choose something else.

Comment: Also, it would be much better if you (edited the question and) provided the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for the 3 tables involved. Much more info so people here can help you better.

Comment: And could you please provide DML (INSERT INTO TABLE blah VALUES(.....) ) for your data - otherwise those who wish to help you have to manually do this, which is painstaking and error-prone. Check out the "help us to help you" blog at the bottom left of the page.

Comment: This guy has got a gold badge for a *famous* question that has been closed. StackExchange needs to review its closure policies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, you want to get all trip_id values that appear in the table, against one stop_id on one or more rows, **and** against another stop_id **on other rows**. This should do it:

```
select trip_id 
from stop_times 
where stop_id = 1538 
or stop_id = 1540
group by trip_id
having count(distinct stop_id) > 1;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e78aa/1

Notice that trip_id 0051ML66220600132483 matches on one stop but not the other, so is not returned.

Comment: I suppose you could replace `OR` with `IN`: `WHERE stop_id IN (1538, 1540)`

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your first query.

```
where stop_id=1538 AND stop_id =1540;
```

A field in a specific row can never have two different values. Its one or another.
If you change your query to `where stop_id=1538 OR stop_id=1540` maybe you get the result that you want.
Regarding the slow query execution, you might wanna create an index on your columns. If you don't have previleges to do so, ask your DBA.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your original query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT trip_id FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id IN(1538,1540);
```

That will bring all the distinct `trip_id` that matches the `stop_id`s that you will have specified in the where clause